# I cant use hooks in securitytextEntry in React native

Tags: react-native

This language is React native

```
export default function forgotPassword(props) {
      const [hidePassword, showPassword] = useState(true);
    
      const managePasswordVisibility = () => {
        showPassword({ hidePassword: !hidePassword });
      };
    
      return (
        <View style={styles.textBoxBtnHolder}>
          <TextInput
            secureTextEntry={hidePassword}
            textContentType="password"
            style={styles.textBox}
          />
          <TouchableOpacity
            activeOpacity={0.8}
            style={styles.visibilityBtn}
            onPress={managePasswordVisibility}
          >
            <Image
              source={
                hidePassword
                  ? require("../../assets/icons/hide.png")
                  : require("../../assets/icons/view.png")
              }
              style={styles.btnImage}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      );
    }
```

i cant able to use hide password in securityTextEntry if i use hooks its showing error and the password is not showing its just hided and its thows a warning .please any one help

```
failed prop 'secureTextEntry' of type 'object' suppied to 'forwardRef(TextInput) expected boolen
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use object inside `showPassword()`, it will only change value of `hidePassword` so

```
showPassword(!hidePassword);
```